# Detect when ListView is scrolled "up" or "down"? Windows Phone 8.1 ListView

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1, scrollbar

Hey how can I detect when my ListView is scrolled up or down?

I have this:

```
 private void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var scrollViewer = MyListView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
     scrollViewer.ViewChanged += BarScroll;
 }

 private void BarScroll(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     var scrollbars = (sender as ScrollViewer).GetDescendantsOfType<ScrollBar>().ToList();
     var verticalBar = scrollbars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical);

     if (verticalBar) (/*If ListView is scrolled up*/)
     {
        //Code when the ListView is scrolled up
     }
     else (/*If ListView is scrolled down*/)
     {
        //Code for when the ListView is scrolled down
     } 
 }
```

Do I need to do something with "verticalBar.Height > verticalBar.ActualHeight"?

Comment: How do you acces to verticalBar var when the BarScroll function stack is closed? don't you have a compilation failure while compiling an if/else outside interface or class?

Comment: The "if/else" was a sample, indeed confusing... Fixed.

Comment: You mean if it is totally scrolled up or totally scrolled down? Or do you want to know if it is being scrolled up or if it is being scrolled down?

Comment: @Meneses when it's scrolled up or down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your BarScroll handler in such way and add private variable to your main class to keep old value of scroll offset:

```
    private double offset;

    private void BarScroll(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double newOffset = (sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset;
        if ( newOffset > offset )
        {
            //Logic for scroll down
        }
        else if ( newOffset < offset )
        {
            //Logic for scroll up
        }

        offset = newOffset;
    }
```